# What is the permission scope of publishing a post users wall in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I published a post to page successfully by using Facebook Grap API over postman tool.
There are informations below for publish post in a page:

**Post Request:** `{{url}}/{{pageId}}/feed?access_token={{page_access_token}}&message=This is a test`

**Scope:** `pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,pages_read_user_content,pages_show_list`

But I want to publish a post to user's own timeline (other says user's wall).
I explore this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post#Creating

They wrote this: *You can publish posts by using the /{user-id}/feed, /{page-id}/feed, /{event-id}/feed, or /{group-id}/feed edges.*

Then I used below informations for a publishing a post on user's wall.

**Post Request:** `{{url}}/{{userId}}/feed?access_token={{user_access_token}}&message=This is a test`

**Scope:** `pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,pages_read_user_content,pages_show_list`

After trying it didn't work. Response is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\n          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "*****"
    }
}
```

{{url}} are tried as https://graph.facebook.com and https://graph.facebook.com/v14.07

Which scopes, url and path should I use?

How can I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: There is no way to publish on users wall.

Comment: That possibility has been removed ages ago, I think it was with introduction of API version 2.4. All you can do is offer the user the chance to actively, manually share something via the Share or Feed dialog.